# Calculate class Cylinder using class Circle

Tags: c++, class, constructor

The constructor of class "Circle" allows the radius to be specified via a parameter, while it is not possible to create objects of the `Circle` type without specifying the parameter. Also, automatic conversion of real numbers into `Circle` objects must not be allowed. The `Set` method, which does the same thing as a constructor, should also be supported, except that it allows the radius of an already created object to be changed later.

The `Cylinder` class constructor requires two parameters that represent the base radius and the height of the roller, respectively. Instances of this class also cannot be created without specifying the mentioned information. It should also support the "Set" function, which does the same thing as a constructor, except that it allows you to modify an already created object.

Both classes must have other methods (listed in code).

I need to use class `Circle` inside class `Cylinder` to enable calculating volume, area, and other functions.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

class Circle {
  double radius;

  public:
  Circle(double r);
  void Set(double r);
  double GetRadius() const;
  double GetPerimeter() const;
  double GetArea() const;
  void Scale(double s);
  void Print() const;
};

class Cylinder {
  Circle baze;
  double height;

  public:
  Cylinder(double r_baze, double h);
  void Set(double r_baze, double h);
  Circle GetBaze() const;
  double GetRadiusOfBaze() const;
  double GetHeight() const;
  double GetArea() const;
  double GetVolume() const;
  void Scale(double s);
  void Print() const;
};

int main() { 
  return 0; 
}

Circle::Circle(double r) {
  radius = r;
}

void Circle::Set(double r) {
  radius = r;
}

double Circle::GetRadius() const { return radius; }

double Circle::GetPerimeter() const { return 2 * 4 * atan(1) * radius; }

double Circle::GetArea() const { return radius * radius * 4 * atan(1); }

void Circle::Scale(double s) {
  radius *= s;
}

void Circle::Print() const {
  std::cout << "R= " << GetRadius() << " O= " << GetPerimeter()
            << " P= " << GetRadius();
}

Cylinder::Cylinder(double r_baze, double h) {
  baze.GetRadius() = r_baze;
  height = h;
}

void Cylinder::Set(double r_baze, double h) {
  baze.GetRadius() = r_baze;
  height = h;
}

Circle Cylinder::GetBaze() const { return baze; }

double Cylinder::GetRadiusOfBaze() const { return baze.GetRadius(); }

double Cylinder::GetHeight() const { return height; }

double Cylinder::GetArea() const {
  return baze.GetArea() * 2 + baze.GetPerimeter() * height;
}

double Cylinder::GetVolume() const { return baze.GetArea() * height; }

void Cylinder::Scale(double s) {
  baze.GetRadius() *= s;
  height *= s;
}

void Cylinder::Print() const {
  std::cout << "R= " << baze.GetRadiusOfBaze() << " H= " << height
            << " P= " << GetArea() << " V= " << GetVolume();
}
```

I'm new to objected-oriented programming concept. Could you help me to understand where I'm making mistakes?

I cannot compile this, because I get errors:

> 57 : no matching function for call to ‘Circle::Circle()’
>
> 14: note: candidate: ‘Circle::Circle(double)’
>
> 14: note: candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
>
> 3: note: candidate: ‘constexpr Circle::Circle(const Circle&)’
>
> 3: note: candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
>
> 62, 70, 91 : lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Comment: ***because I get some errors*** What errors? Please edit your question and add the exact text of the error messages.

Comment: @drescherjm I added errors

Comment: For the first error "no matching function for call to ‘Circle::Circle()’" you need this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)

Comment: Also, the `GetRadius()` function is for reading the value, not for changing it. Hint: There is also a `Set()` function.

Comment: Is the assignment missing the location parameters, such as `x,y` in Cartesian Coordinate System?

Comment: You may simplify your code by having `Cylinder` inherit from `Circle`.  In one view, a cylinder has all the same methods and members that a circle does.  On the other hand, a Cylinder is made up of (contains) an infinite quantity of circles.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Task doesn't say anything about x and y coordinates, this doesn't require that. This is simple circle and cylinder.

Comment: @BoP in function `Set` I don't know how to access radius of baze, that's problem... radius of class Circle is private, so I cannot access with `baze.radius` I should access it with function `GetRadius`

Comment: `baze` has its own `Set` function. Just call that from the derived class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Cylinder::Cylinder(double r_baze, double h) {
>  baze.GetRadius() = r_baze;
>  height = h;
> }
> ```

In your `Cylinder` class, when your constructor is called, `baze` is implicitly initialized with a default constructor that does not exist.

You want to use an [*initializer list*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor) to handle that initialization, at which point the code inside your `Cylinder` constructor becomes unnecessary.

```
Cylinder::Cylinder(double r_baze, double h) 
: baze(r_baze), height(h) {
}
```

Alternatively, you could provide functionally a default constructor for your `Circle` class, and then `Set` the radius in `Cylinder`'s constructor, but that's more work.

```
Circle::Circle(double r=0.0) {
  radius = r;
}

Cylinder::Cylinder(double r_baze, double h) {
  baze.Set(r_baze);
  height = h;
}
```

*Also...*

Please note that `GetRadius` returns a `double` and cannot be assigned to, so you will get an error on that line of code.

Comment: thank you very much, do you know how could I make this `baze.GetRadius() = r_baze;` and `baze.GetRadius() *= s;` work? How to access radius of baze using function GetRadius(), is there any way to use reference for that?

Comment: or pointer `this`?

Comment: @drescherjm It has, look at the code `void Cylinder::Set(double r_baze, double h)` but I have problem with that, I cannot access radius of baze, I don't know how to access it...